# SSD doesn't respond to anything after trying to reformat broken NTFS on it

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk, ntfs, partition-table

A week ago or so my windows 10 completely died and took my windows apps partition with it. I was however able to access all data from within my linux, so I did what any person would do and copied any data that mattered to another drive. As the partition was still broken and unreadable from within windows I decided I need to delete the partition and reformat the drive. So I opened the graphical partitioning tool on my desktop (manjaro KDE, so KDE Partition Manager) and queued the actions, delete partition 1, Microsoft reserved Partition... partition 2, the actual data partition. Then create a new partition on the entire drive.

well... after I did that the tool spat out an error with sfdisk and the drive now no longer shows up in parted, fdisk or gparted, while the KDE tool shows a drive with no partitions and the size of 0B. I can't even read the smart parameters.... In the GUI its greyed out,

hdparm:

```
> sudo hdparm -Ii /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: No message of desired type
```

smartctl:

```
> sudo smartctl -aT permissive /dev/sda  

smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.16-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Short INQUIRY response, skip product id

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK
Current Drive Temperature:     0 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        0 C

Read defect list: asked for grown list but didn't get it
Error Counter logging not supported

Device does not support Self Test logging
```

lsblk:

```
> lsblk

NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0     0B  0 disk 
sdb           8:16   0   3,6T  0 disk 
├─sdb1        8:17   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdb2        8:18   0   2,7T  0 part /mnt/media
└─sdb3        8:19   0   932G  0 part /mnt/backup01
sdc           8:32   0   1,8T  0 disk 
├─sdc1        8:33   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdc2        8:34   0   128M  0 part 
├─sdc3        8:35   0 506,8G  0 part /mnt/win7
├─sdc4        8:36   0   1,1T  0 part /mnt/backup02
└─sdc5        8:37   0 268,4G  0 part /mnt/apps
sdd           8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdd1        8:49   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdd2        8:50   0    16M  0 part 
├─sdd3        8:51   0 930,9G  0 part /mnt/win10
└─sdd4        8:52   0   509M  0 part 
sde           8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   301M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0  97,5G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 122,1G  0 part /home
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 245,9G  0 part /mnt/data01
```

In the GUI tool the only option it offers me now is to create a new partition table, but trying that only returns

```
Command: sfdisk --wipe=always /dev/sda 
Create new partition table on device ‘/dev/sda’: Error
Create a new partition table (type: gpt) on ‘/dev/sda’: Error
```

One thing I am thinking of trying is to go into my new windows install and see if I have any luck with the partitioning tools there, but honestly this drive looks kinda dead right now... Which would be awful as it is a 2TB SSD, those aren't cheap.

Any idea what to do, to get the drive back to a working state?

---

EDIT:
after rebooting the system I found the drive in the same state from before I tried to erase it. I could now read out the smart parameters:

```
> sudo smartctl -aT permissive /dev/sda
 
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.15.16-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SanDisk SSD PLUS 2000GB
Serial Number:    2025BG450511
LU WWN Device Id: 5 001b44 4a773f82e
Firmware Version: UP4504RL
User Capacity:    2.000.398.934.016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
TRIM Command:     Available, deterministic
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jan 31 18:07:24 2022 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
No failed Attributes found.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x11) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        No Auto Offline data collection support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        No Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 255) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7810
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       487
165 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       968
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       6
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       93
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       23
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1098
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   063   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (Min/Max 13/76)
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2525458858572
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       12437
234 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26146
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       9989
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10056
244 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   000   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

Selective Self-tests/Logging not supported
```

KDE Partition Manager shows:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried power cycling? If it still doesn't work after that, it's most likely physically dead.

Comment: I power cycled and the data appears on it again, however... even after swapping SATA cable and port on the mainboard, every time I try to erase the disk I end up with the same situation described here. Meaning the drive never actually gets deleted.. it can not be written to either though.

Comment: `SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!` RMA or dispose of.

Comment: Microsoft requires the System Reserved before NTFS partition on a drive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition  Does gdisk show drive correctly? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Answer (score 0):

as the comments and the SMART info on the drive say, my drive seems to be dying indeed. The only thing I can (and will now) do is to RMA it. I had purchased the drive in september 2020, so ~16 months ago. less that 2 years. Per european consumer protection laws I can and will ask for a refund. Luckily I was able to rescue all important data from it before it gives in entirely. I am a bit at unease though as the data is still readable and I would prefer to not send a drive back, with my data on it. even if it is mostly apps.
Another approach would be to flash the controller firmware of the SSD. This would only work if the firmware is the damaged part, not the actual storage chips. I am not sure how to proceed with that at this point, but it is an option... albeit that is probably a rather slim chance.

Either way, I hope this post will help someone in the future to determine faster, what has happened to their drive.